# Meaning of "Twice Upon a Time" and its usage in a sentence

Tags: descriptive-grammar

This is my first question on english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. Could anyone tell me the meaning of "Twice Upon a Time"? It's the title of Doctor Who's Christmas special episode, the last of this ongoing season. I have been browsing the web for quite some time now and been exposed to a variety of uncertain answers.

Comment: an event that occurred twice in a specific time/time frame? I'm not sure

Comment: Context is everything. Where did you find this expression?

Comment: It's the title of Doctor who's Christmas special episode ,last of this ongoing season

Comment: I think you'll have to figure that one out for yourself, but it may well have to do with the fact that it starts with two doctors. This is not a phrase in common usage.

Comment: 'Once upon a time' is a set phrase appearing in many childrens (no apostrophe) books of a certain era. 'Twice upon a time' is a tongue-in-cheek tweak. It probably makes some sort of sense given the context in which it's used.

Comment: 'Once upon a time' is the classic way of beginning any traditional story, meaning 'At some (unspecified) time in the past...'

Comment: @KateBunting well apparently that's not  what I asked  for

Comment: I think it _is_ what you asked for, because it is a one-of wordplay. The standard expression i s_once upon a time_ and normally there is _one_ doctor. Supposedly someone familiar with the expression _once upon a time_ would see the playful connection between the mangled _twice upon a time_ and the fact that there are two doctors now.

Comment: Yeah, it's a play on the story-telling idiom "Once upon a time".

Comment: VD, have you watched the episode - or the whole series; I don't mind - please?

Comment: @VD_ixy I was merely adding further explanation of Edwin's comment.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, "Twice Upon a Time" is the title of the Doctor Who 2017 Christmas Special.

It's playing with the standard expression "Once upon a time," traditionally used to introduce fairy stories and the like.

There is normally only one eponymous doctor in the show. This one features two.

[See this promotional link.](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2017-12-05/doctor-who-2017-christmas-special-release-date-time-cast-plot/)

> Twice Upon a Time will see Peter Capaldi’s Twelfth Doctor team up with his earlier self the First Doctor (David Bradley), as the pair both try to avoid regenerating (and therefore changing their appearance and personality).

Personally, I am looking forward to watching it!

Now that I've watched the show (some time ago), I've edited my post to add Lawrence's comment.

> > It could also be a reference to the Doctor (single person, albeit appearing in two forms at the same time) needing to make the same decision twice, with the decision-making processes linked to each other temporally and perhaps organically (for want of a better term) as well.

Comment: It could also be a reference to the Doctor (single person, albeit appearing in 2 forms at the same time) needing to make the same decision twice, with the decision-making processes linked to each other temporally and perhaps organically (for want of a better term) as well.

Comment: @Lawrence, indeed. Now that I have actually seen the show, I think your explanation is good.

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer.